# I need to stop the timer and run a frame animation

Tags: java, android, timer, android-animation

I have a game where image Views changes on a timer. When a button is clicked (stop) the update is called to update score and spins. I need to stop when the whammy(); is called and run a frame animation then start the timer back when the animation has ended. I have tried to call sleep(2500); but it cause the everything to wait the 2.5 seconds and the frame animation then runs with the image view timer. That just won't work for what I need. Below is the section of code I need help with:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btstop) {
        final Button bstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btstop);
        bstop.setEnabled(false);
        updateState();
    }
}

/**
 * set random view. get random 1 point from class utils and display to 1
 * position random
 */
public void setRandomView() {
    int item = new Random().nextInt(18);
    current = Utils.getAPoint();
    int img = current.getImg();
    int score = current.getScore();
    int spin = current.getSpin();
    iv[item].setImageResource(img);
    dataPoint.get(item).setImg(img);
    dataPoint.get(item).setScore(score);
    dataPoint.get(item).setSpin(spin);
    ivcenter.setImageResource(img);

}

/**
 * display Name,score & spin to screen
 */
public void setPoint() {
    tvspin.setText(spins + "\n" + name);
    tvpoint.setText(point + "");
}

/**
 * Start Thread Sets the speed of the game board Enable STOP button to true
 * 
 * @param time
 */
public void start(int time) {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(time, 300) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // call to set random view
            setRandomView();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }.start();

}

/**
 * stop timer thread
 */
public void stop() {
    try {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    } finally {
    }
}

/**
 * update state game and check what tile is in the center
 */
public void updateState() { // get score,spin current point
    int scoreCurrent = current.getScore();
    int spinCurrent = current.getSpin();
    spins--;// Take one from spins

    // if score = 2, that mean to double score
    if (scoreCurrent == 2) {
        point = point * 2;
        playmp3(R.raw.correct);
    }

    // if score = 0, that means tile is a whammy
    if (scoreCurrent == 0) {
        playmp3(R.raw.buzz);
        whammy();// I need to put everything else on hold here and animation here
        point = 0;// sets the score to 0
        whammy++; // Add a whammy to the whammy count

        // Display the whammy that was added
        for (int i = 0; i < whammy; i++) {
            popup[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        // sleep(2500);
        if (whammy == 4) {
            stop();
            stopmp3();
            callFinish();
        }
    }
    // else ,score = score current + point.getscore
    else {
        playmp3(R.raw.correct);
        point = point + scoreCurrent;
    }
    // spins--;// Take one from spint

    // if spin > 0, that mean is add a spin
    if (spinCurrent > 0) {
        spins = spins + spinCurrent;
    }
    setPoint(); // display spin,score and name to screen

    sleep(2000); // Adds a delay so that the whammy pop up can be seen

    // if spint >0 start new data random
    if (spins > 0) {
        stop();
        final Button bstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btstop);
        bstop.setEnabled(true);
        start(10000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    } else {
        // stop all
        stop();
        stopmp3();
        // if spin < 2, that round <2 move to spin activity
        if (round < 2) {
            Intent it = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SpinActivity.class);
            startActivity(it);
            finish();
        }
        // else move to high score activity
        else {
            callFinish();
        }
    }
}

private void whammy() {
    // set up the whammy act animation
    final ImageView act = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.whammyact);
    act.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tnt_animation);
    actAnim = (AnimationDrawable) act.getBackground();
    actAnim.setVisible(true, true);

}
```

Comment: Any suggestions will be welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Here are the changes that were made to make the animation run and finish before the game timer gets started back...

IF THERE ARE QUESTION OR ANYONE NEED HELP FEEL FREE TO ASK.

```
        if (scoreCurrent == 0) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer = null;
        // Use Timer to set visibility to GONE after the animation finishes.            
                    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            PressActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                public void run() {
                                    resumeLogicAfterPress();
                                }
                            });}};
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(timerTask, getWhammyAnimationTotalDuration(actAnim));
    } else {
        resumeLogicAfterPress();
    }

}

public void resumeLogicAfterPress() {
    // Display the whammy that was added
            for (int i = 0; i < whammy; i++) {
                popup[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }


            sleep(2500); //Adds a delay so that the whammy pop up can be seen

            //Start the background music
            playmp3(mpPress, R.raw.press);
            // if whammy = 4. stop all and move to high score
            if (whammy == 4) {
                stop();
                stopmp3();
                callFinish();
            }
            // if spint >0 start new data random
            if (spint > 0) {
                stop();
                final Button bstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btstop);
                bstop.setEnabled(true);
                start(10000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
            } else {
                // stop all
                stop();
                stopmp3();
                // if spin < 2, that round <2 move to spin activity
                if (spin < 2) {
                    Intent it = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SpinActivity.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                    finish();
                }
                // esle move to high score activity
                else {
                    callFinish();
                }
            }
}

private void whammy() {
    // set up the whammy act animation
    final ImageView act = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.whammyact);
    act.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tnt_animation);
    actAnim = (AnimationDrawable) act.getBackground();
    actAnim.setVisible(true, true); 
    }
```